# Which metric is not complete?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

## Problem

Which one of the following metric is not complete on $\mathbb R$:

1. $|x-y|$
2. $|arctan(x) - arctan(y)|$
3. $|x^3 - y^3|$
4. $|x^{1/3} - y^{1/3}|$

1 is complete. I am not sure about the 2, 3 and 4.

For 2, I do not know the definition of $arc$ function

For $3. 4$, they can be viewed as the special case of $|f(x) - f(y)|$, note that
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(\theta)||x-y|
$$
where $x< \theta < y$.

it seems that 3&4 are complete with respect to the intervals, but what about $\mathbb R$

Comment: Only one of the above is a norm in the usual sense of the word. I presume you meant distance rather than norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know 1 is complete. Denote this distance by $d$.

For 2 (presumably $\arctan$), the sequence $x_n = n$ is Cauchy but
clearly does not converge.

For 3 & 4, suppose $f$ is odd, continuous, strictly increasing, unbounded
and $f(0) = 0$ (the latter follows since $f$ is odd). Then I claim that $\rho(x,y) = |f(x)-f(y)|$ is a complete
metric.

Note that $f$ has an inverse $g$ such that $g(f(x)) = x$.
It is straightforward to show that $g$ is continuous.

Suppose $x_n$ is $\rho$-Cauchy. It follows that $f(x_n)$ is bounded. Since $g$ is uniformly continuous on bounded sets, it follows that
for any $\epsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that if
$\rho(x_n,x_m)=|f(x_n)-f(x_m)| < \delta$, then $|g(f(x_n))-g(f(x_m))| = |x_n-x_m| < \epsilon$. It follows that $x_n$ is Cauchy with respect to the
standard distance, and hence there is some $x$ such that $x_n \to x$ with respect to $d$. It follows from continuity that $\rho(x_n,x) \to 0$
as well and hence $\rho$ is a complete metric.

Now check that $x \mapsto x^3, x \mapsto \sqrt[3]{x}$ satisfy the
conditions above.